# Can anyone help me with this SAT math question?

Tags: geometry

Cara is hanging a poster that is 91 centimeters wide in her room. The center of the wall is 180 cm from the right end of the wall. If Cara hangs the poster so that the center of the poster is located at the center of the wall, how far will the left and right edges of the poster be from the right end?

Answer (score 1):

Start by drawing a diagram showing what you know and what you want to find out

```
Left          Mid          Right
 |        _____|_____        |
 |       |           |       |
 |       |    pic    |       |
 |       |___________|       |
 |             |             |
 |       |     |     |       |
 |             |             |
 |       |     |     |       |
 |       ----91cm-----       |  "poster is 91cm wide"
 |       |     |----180cm----|  "center of wall 180cm from right end"
 |             |     |--?cm--|  "distance of right edge"
 |       |--------?cm--------|  "distance of left edge"
```

You can probably draw a better one than mine on paper, but hopefully it will give you a starting point